# Semaphore functions

Tags: c, winapi

moin-moin,

I need the MS Visual C (6.0) equivalent for the functions "DosEnterCritSec()" and "DosExitCritSec()", which garantees, that no two threads are executing the enclosed code at the same time.

Can anybody please point me into the right direction?

Thanks a lot,
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EnterCriticalSection() / LeaveCriticalSection()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with `DoesEnterCritSec()` and `DosExitCritSec()` but based on:

> that no two threads are executing the enclosed code at the same time.

you can use [`EnterCriticalSection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`LeaveCriticalSection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Each thread must use the same instance of a `CRITICAL_SECTION`.

See [Using Critical Sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you'll be looking for critical sections.

Somewhere, often during startup, you need to initialize:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION mutex;
InitializeCriticalSection(&mutex);
```

Then in your re-entrant code:

```
EnterCriticalSection(&mutex);
/* Do some thread-safe stuff */
LeaveCriticalSection(&mutex);
```

As a bonus, if you enter the same critical section multiple times in the same thread, you won't lock yourself out (as long as you leave it the same number of times).

Comment: There also also in Windows entities which *are* called mutexes, so it's not prudent to name a critical section variable "mutex".